# Method Not Allowed with flask application in python

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to make a sign in page with flask and i keep getting this error message

Method Not Allowed

this is main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
app = Flask('app')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
@app.route('/home')
def home():
  return "home"

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

this is templates/login.html

```
  <head>
    <title>Flask Intro - login page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Please login</h1>
      <br>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="{{
          request.form.username }}">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="{{
          request.form.password }}">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Login">
      </form>
      {% if error %}
        <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explicitly allow POST on any endpoints you want to use it.

> By default, a route only answers to `GET` requests. You can use the methods argument of the `route()` decorator to handle different HTTP methods.

```py
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    ...
```

### Reference:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods